# Ubuntu Software Center closes immediately after opening

Tags: software-center

Opening Ubuntu Software Center results in it closing 1-2 seconds later. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you open Terminal, enter `software-center` and add the output to your question?

Comment: I'm having the same error in Ubuntu 16.04. When I type `ubuntu-software` in Terminal, I get [this](http://pastebin.com/NGj6gRUf) output.

Answer (score 28):

Re-installing Ubuntu Software helped me.

Run the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gnome-software-common
```

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I think I had to update my software center. Terminal told me it wasn't installed. Don't know how that happened, I've used it before, but not for awhile now. After installing, I still could only open it from the terminal (as opposed to from my desktop). I had to unlock it from my bar, and relock the new center to it. Even then, I couldn't install skype until I opened it into the new software center. Everything works, but damn that was confusing.

Comment: It gives me

**Bus error (core dumped). 0%**

Error but after run **sudo apt-get update** command i am able to do that

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS